# How exactly are these two formulas different from each other? (One is valid and the other is invalid)

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have this formula:

$$\forall y\exists x.\quad P(x,y)\quad \Rightarrow \quad \exists x\forall y.\quad P(x,y)$$

and this one:

$$\exists x\forall y.\quad P(x,y)\quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall y\exists x.\quad P(x,y).$$

I am told that the first one is valid and the second one isn’t.

I am trying to understand how the second formula is not valid in comparison to the first. To me, it seems as if both statements are the same exact thing and I find it very hard to distinguish between the both of them. Please explain this to me like I am 5. I’m just starting to study discrete math, so a lot of this is new to me.

*This was taken from MIT OCW's Mathematics for Computer Science*

Comment: Are you sure the first one is valid?

Comment: This is not (discrete-mathematics).

Comment: @Did at least in the us this would be covered in a computer science course named discrete mathematics.

Comment: @Did according to MIT, this is discrete math.

Comment: @MattSamuel Seriously, what is "discrete" in the logical quantifiers "for all" and "exists"? The tag (discrete-mathematics) reads "The study of discrete mathematical structures", which seems quite correct and does not refer to said quantifiers. One could even argue that many people first meet "for all" and "exists" when given the formal definition of continuity, that is, when they start to study seriously a typically *non discrete* property...

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Not so sure about this, actually the course is called "Mathematics for Computer Science" and its description starts with "This course covers elementary discrete mathematics for computer science and engineering. It emphasizes mathematical definitions and proofs as well as applicable methods." You stopped at the first sentence but, of course, quantifiers are involved if one wants to emphasize "mathematical definitions and proofs".

Comment: @Did I don't necessarily agree with the names of the courses, just making an observation.

Comment: @MattSamuel Understood.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it backwards. The second one is valid, the first is not. To see that the second is valid, suppose there exists a special $x$ such that $P(x,y)$ holds for all $y$. Then for each $y$ there is an $x$ such that $P(x,y)$, and even more so the same $x$ works for all $y$.

On the other hand, suppose that for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $P(x,y)$. Then $x$ could be different for every different $y$, so it's not automatically guaranteed that there is an $x$ that works for all $y$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of the proposition $(1)$  we have $\exists x\, \forall y$, which means there is (at least) an $x$, say $x_0$, which is suitable for every $y$ such that $P(x_0,y)$ is true. Thus, it is implied that for every $y$ we can find (at least) an $x$ (more particularly the $x_0$) such that $P(x,y)$ is true.

In the first part of the proposition $(2)$ we have $\forall y, \exists x$, which means for every $y$ we can find an $x$, which depends on the choice of $y$ ( usually denoted as $x_y$ or $x(y)$ ) such that $P(x,y)$ is true.  However, this does **not** imply that there is a universal $x$ such that for every $y$ $P(x,y)$ is true.